# How to remove data from a field in elk

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am quite new but not so new in elastic stack and have a need for my company to delete data from a field

example
I have a field sent after being parsed on logstash to elasticsearch

let's call it remain_logs

If we read it from kibana on discover tab, we can see it values:

remain_logs: commtype=data, info=user action=changepwd matricule=000120 UPDATED
but it can be also:
remain_logs: commtype=data, info=user action=changepwd matricule=000120 DELETED
remain_logs: commtype=data, info=user action=changepwd matricule=000120 CREATED

whatever in the end.
actually, all those values, commtype are already added as a field so we don't need to show them again on remaing_logs

so basically is going on remain_logs docs and remove everything but the end of the line

I tried to do it through mutate { remove_field{}} in logstash but not results
and don't know much on painless or scripted fields?

what would be the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your problem correctly (removing a field from every document in a given index), you could use the `_update_by_query` endpoint. For example:

```
POST your_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": "ctx._source.remove('name_of_the_field_to_remove')"
}
```

docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html

Comment: I don't want to remove a field, i want to remove data inside a field.
If you are talking about fields added on an index, the field is remain_logs

inside remain logs on every daily index i have datas, and on those datas i want to remove everything listed, example commtype=data, info=user action=changepwd matricule=000120

those are not fields on the index, just datas i want to remove from the remain_logs field

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to update the field's values to null. This worked for me.

```
POST <index_name>/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """

   if (ctx._source?.Field != null) 
    {  
        ctx._source.remove('remain_logs');
        ctx._source.put('remain_logs', '');
    }   
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
        "_id": [
          1 (Replace with Document ID)
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

PS: This might take longer to update if `refresh_interval` in your elasticsearch's configuration is set to a higher value.